# What version of Virtual PC do I have?

Tags: microsoft-virtual-pc, version

How do I find the version number of Virtual PC that I'm running?

For example, launching Virtual PC, goes to a folder of virtual machines, but there is no About menu item for Virtual PC itself. Going to the Programs and Features area show Virtual PC under windows features but no version number is listed. How do I know if I'm running the most up to date version?

I'm on Windows 7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it.  To get the version of Virtual PC that is running when you are on Windows 7, open a virtual machine and select the Help icon in the upper-right-hand corner of that window.  Clicking that will show a drop down menu of three options. One of those options is "About Virtual PC" and that has version info.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the icon and select "Show Virtual PC Console":

[image]

There you will find the about menu item under "Help":

[image]

And your version:

[image]

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Virtual_PC) has information regarding the latest version.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm on Windows 7 and don't have a Virtual PC item in my system tray.

Comment: In taskbar properties uncheck "Hide inactive icons". It should be there.

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 so I don't have the "Hide inactive icons" option.  I do have "Always show all icons and notifications".  But this still does not show Virtual PC console. I think things are different in Windows 7 than Windows XP.  In Windows 7, the Help menu of Virtual PC itself has the "About Virtual PC" menu option.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Virtual PC 6.0.192.0 on Windows XP, so it could be different elsewhere. But in the Virtual PC Console go to the `Help` menu and select `About Virtual PC...`